# Making rank 4 numpy array from flat list of pixels to use in ImageDataGenerator in Keras and then in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, keras

I have dataframe that consists of greascale(c=1) images of  dimension `137*236` that makes a total of `32332` pixels. I want to augment each image using  `ImageDataGenerator()` but it thros an error as  `Invalid dimensions for image data`  when I use the code below

```
samples = np.expand_dims(df.iloc[[65],1:].values.reshape(137,236,1), 0)
# create image data augmentation generator
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(width_shift_range=[-200,200])
# prepare iterator
it = datagen.flow(samples, batch_size=1)
# generate samples and plot
for i in range(9):
    # define subplot
    pyplot.subplot(330 + 1 + i)
    # generate batch of images
    batch = it.next()
    # convert to unsigned integers for viewing
    image = batch[0].astype('uint8')
    print(image.shape)
    pyplot.imshow(image)
    # show the figure
    pyplot.show()
```

and shows errors as `` 'Input data in `NumpyArrayIterator` should have rank 4. You passed an array with shape', (1, 137, 236) ``  when I use `samples = np.expand_dims(df.iloc[[65],1:].values.reshape(137,236), 0)` ?

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Please share the full stack trace. And what is `df` like (shape/description)?